# CSS3 - Verticle Angled 80% OUTER Box Shadow

Tags: css, shadow

I know how to make a box shadow run down an element however is it possible to have it extend down 80% of the element instead of the entire height of the element?

Also how to make the shadow angle out (this is the thing im struggling with most)

[image]

Comment: No - not directly. You would have to overlay it or use `:before`/`:after`.

Comment: I figured i would have to use :before/:after with a bunch of rotates or something, figured id ask before i spend a few hours tryin to figure it out, would rather not use images

Comment: You should just position a element behind it with 80% of the height

Comment: I may not have worded my question the best but it has to go 80% and then it has to casually fade out(45 degrees) on an angle, think of a rectangle with a right angle triangle at the bottom

Comment: Not quite following.. I will write an answer if you provide an image of what its suppose to look like.

Comment: Alright - I get it. It's like a 3D effect.

Comment: Im stupid, its an outer shadow (been working like 20 hours), forgive my awful drawing but essientially the shadow runs down the side of the div (easy to accomplish) but where im stumped is how to make it angle out and not extend down the entire div. (normally i wouldnt do this but the project requires it)

Comment: How many issues do you think I will have with older browsers with something like this lol

Comment: Something like.. http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Comment: Thats not as bad as i expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bHEaZ/)

There are a bunch of ways you could achieve this.. I just set the shadow, and overlayed a triangle.

[image]

Here is an alternative without the blurred shadow.. http://jsfiddle.net/bHEaZ/1/

**HTML** - pretty simple

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 20px -10px 30px black;
    margin: 40px;
}

div:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 102px;
    top: 100px;
    content: "\A";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 90px solid white;
    border-right: 50px solid white;
    border-top: 90px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: exactly, obviously needs a little finesse but ill work that out :P thanks a lot

Comment: @JMcFee I didn't have to use the CSS transform/rotate effect, but I still obviously had to use `:after`, which is only supported by ie8+

Comment: Yup thats fine, im not worried about it ill just try to have it degrade to a shadow all the way down the div for anyone that unfortunately uses ie7 and under

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?
http://fiddle.jshell.net/sijav/2S7Pv/1/ 
There is bunch of ways you can do that, but my way is:
use another div and radius border it then put it behind the actual div ...

```
.origdiv{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: blue;
    z-index:10;
}
.shadowthis{
    left:150px;
    top:150px;
    position:absolute;
    box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px #888888;
    border-bottom-right-radius:25%;
    z-index:9;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: ya you pretty much got it but as @JoshC was doing using the :before/:after is a little cleaner and with the progression in browsers i shouldnt have to many conflicts